# Pass jQuery parameter with different name

Tags: jquery, css, function, parameters

I want to choose the css settings based on the existance of a data tag. Which is the right way to do it?

```
            var datadirection = 'left'; //default direction

            if( $(this).attr('data-right') ){
                datadirection = 'right';
             }

            $(this).css({
                datadirection : fxpositionX + 'px'
            }).transition({
                datadirection : '0px'
            });
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You can do `if( $(this).data('right') ){` in jQuery :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the object with the property values first, which will be a little more verbose:

```
var css = {};
css[datadirection] = fxpositionX + 'px';

var transition = {}
transition[datadirection] = '0px';

$(this).css(css).transition(transition);
```

In this specific case you can also take advantage of the fact that `.css` has another signature you can use:

```
$(this).css(datadirection, fxpositionX + 'px');
```

I am not sure what `.transition` is, but do check if it also supports this syntax.